# py2app runs fine in alias mode but not when bundled tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, py2app

I am trying to bundle an app in my Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8. I've python2.7, py27-tkinter installed through macports 2.3.4.

My code runs perfect when run as a script as well as in py2app's alias mode. However, when I bundle it doesn't behave properly: meaning, upon every conditional check on the user input integer, the result should be updated in the window. However, the result is updated only for the first input integer and nothing gets updated for the subsequent inputs. When I try to run interactively, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 18, in 
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 659, in run
    self._run()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 865, in _run
    self.run_normal()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 939, in run_normal
    mf = self.get_modulefinder()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 814, in get_modulefinder
    debug=debug,
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/modulegraph/find_modules.py", line 341, in find_modules
    find_needed_modules(mf, scripts, includes, packages)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/modulegraph/find_modules.py", line 266, in find_needed_modules
    path = m.packagepath[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>>
```

Could anyone shed some light on what is missing/wrong here and how to troubleshoot and ultimately solve the problem?

Many thanks in advance.